# Почему Button теряет свою форму?

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вверху представлены две картинки , в одном из них Button(QWERTY2) теряет истинную форму , когда она содержит количество строк неравное тому количеству, которое имеет его сосед слева(QWERTY1) (сосед имеет 1 строку, а тот 2). Такая же ситуация может произойти с Button-ом QWERTY1,относительно QWERTY2. Естественно, когда у них равное количество строк,кнопки не теряют форму,как вы заметили из первой картинки. В отличие от них с кнопками QWERTY3,QWERTY4 не происходит такого. Как исправить эту проблему таким образом, чтобы кнопки сохраняли свою нормальную форму, независимо от количество слов или строк в них? Внизу мой XML код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="count"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/amount_of_true_answers"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/amount_of_false_answers"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:id="@+id/questCounterId"

        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="true"

        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:id="@+id/amount_of_true_answers"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textColor="#007E41"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Question"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/QuestionText"
        android:layout_above="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/questCounterId"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"


        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="false"
        android:id="@+id/amount_of_false_answers"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="#861F23"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />




        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_above="@+id/a_and_b"

            android:id="@+id/nextButton"

            android:onClick="ShowNextQuestion"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

            android:text=">"

            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

            android:background="@drawable/using_nextprevbuttons"

            android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"

            android:shadowDx="0"

            android:shadowDy="0"

            android:shadowRadius="4"



            android:textSize="32dp"


            />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/c_and_d"
        android:id="@+id/a_and_b"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        >



        <Button


            android:onClick="OptionButtonPressed"
            android:id="@+id/opta"





            android:text="qwerty1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/using_optionshape"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            />

        <Button

            android:id="@+id/optb"
            android:onClick="OptionButtonPressed"





            android:text="qwerty2 qwerty2 qwerty2 "
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/using_optionshape"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

            />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/c_and_d"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"


        >

        <Button


            android:text="qwerty3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/using_optionshape"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"

            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

            android:onClick="OptionButtonPressed"
            android:id="@+id/optc" />

        <Button









            android:text="qwerty4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/using_optionshape"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/optd"
            android:onClick="OptionButtonPressed"
            />
    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете задать вашему LinearLayout (у которого id a_and_b)
параметр `android:gravity="center"`, тогда все что находится внутри него будет отцентровано относительно его самого

Иначе можно задать вашей кнопке (qwerty2 которая) параметр
`android:layout_gravity="center"`, тогда она одна будет отцентрована относительно данного LinearLayout.

Но, даже когда все будет отцентровано, размер кнопки все равно будет чуть больше других, т.к. ее высота wrap_content, т.е. высота определяется содержимым компонента. Чем больше текста вы в нее напишете, тем она больше растянется.

Можете сделать размер кнопок фиксированным, но лучше, поиграйтесь с LinearLayout, сделайте LinearLayout корневым и разбейте страницу на три внутренних лайаута, верхний RelativeLayout и два нижних LinearLayout: в RelativeLayour разместите ваши тексты и кнопку со стрелкой ">", а в двух нижних разместите ваши кнопки (как вы и сделали).

Далее задайте вес этим лайаутам, предположим верхний лайаут будет 70, а два нижних с кнопками будут по 15, после чего задайте кнопкам высоту match_parent.
Кнопки растянутся по всей высоте лайаута, получится то, что нужно. Корневому лайауту задайте параметр android:weightSum="100"

Вот пример:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="80"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="10">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="qwerty1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="qwerty2 qwerty2 qwerty2"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="10">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="qwerty3"
            android:id="@+id/button2"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="qwerty4"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]